# How to remove top margin from SafeViewArea | React Native | iPhoneX

Tags: ios, react-native, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide, safeareaview

I need to use **`SafeViewArea`** for iPhoneX, but when i have putted **`SafeViewArea`** then some unwanted extra margin from top is showing.

[image]

My Code snippet -

```
render () {

    return (

      <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ top: 'always' }} style={styles.applicationView}>
        <View style={styles.applicationView}>
          <StatusBar barStyle='light-content'/>
          <ReduxNavigation/>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
```

styles.js

```
export default StyleSheet.create({
  applicationView: {
    flex: 1
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: Colors.background
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontFamily: Fonts.type.base,
    margin: Metrics.baseMargin
  },
  myImage: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    alignSelf: 'center'
  }
})
```

**EDIT: How to remove the shadow of `SurfaceViewArea`?**

Suggestions appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you include your styles in the question please?

Comment: Can you try to: replace `<ReduxNavigation/>` with `<View style={{backgroundColor:"#fff"}}></View>` .Still have you seen extra margin from top? If you dont, the problem comes from your screen style(in shared image). marginTop or justifyContent:"center" can cause this. {container, welcome, myImage} styles are belong in your shared image?

Comment: @sdkcy its not working.

Comment: StatusBar can causes also. Can you remove it and try? or if you want, share your code as snack.expo?

Comment: I have tried by removing the `StatusBar` but still having the same issue.

Comment: Has anyone fixed this yet?